# How to sum up the word frequencies after stemming in Racket?

Tags: nlp, racket

As background I'm trying to make a NLP application in Racket and I arrived at the part where I have to stem the words (I also obtained their frequency).

I am using the `(planet dyoo/porter-stemmer)` package in order to stem, and as an example we can write:

```
(map (λ(x) (list (stem (first x)) (second x)))
     '(("cryed" 1)
       ("racketeer" 2)
       ("crying" 3)
       ("playing" 4)
       ("racketing" 5)
       ("plays" 6)
       ("Racket" 7)))
```

Which produces: `'(("cry" 1) ("racket" 2) ("cry" 3) ("plai" 4) ("racket" 5) ("plai" 6) ("racket" 7))`

Now my goal is to sum up the frequency for each term, aka to arrive at: `'(("cry" 4) ("racket" 14) ("plai" 10))`

I came up with a way to do it, but I don't like my solution:

```
(define (frequency string)
  (map (λ(x) (list (first x) (length x)))
       (group-by (λ(x) x) (string-split string))))

(define (recalculate lst)
  (frequency
   (string-join
    (flatten
     (map (λ(x) (make-list (second x) (first x))) lst)))))
```

Basically I retype each word as many times as it's frequency, then make a single string containing all words and finally compute the frequency again. Is there a simpler(faster) way to achieve this?

I should perhaps add that the order doesn't matter ("plai" can come up before "cry" and so on). Also I'm looking for a simpler solution because I'm gonna have to use larger datasets and I want to make this faster (I'd also be glad even if the `frequency` function can be made more faster).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an `add-count` procedure that takes a list of counts and a new count as arguments, and adds the count to the list if there are no similarly tagged counts already in the list, or combines the new count with an existing count.

```lisp
#lang racket

(define (get-tag c) (first c))

(define (get-val c) (second c))

(define (add-count cs c)
  (let* ((k (get-tag c))
         (v (get-val c))
         (old-count (assoc k cs)))
    (if old-count
        (cons (list k (+ v (get-val old-count)))
              (remove old-count cs))
        (cons c cs))))
```

Here `get-tag` and `get-val` are just convenience procedures to access the tag and value stored in a count. The [`assoc`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._assoc%29%29) procedure is used to extract a copy of the first count in `cs` matching the new count `c` to be added. This count is stored in `old-count`, the value of which is used to create a new count which is added to the list after removing `old-count` from the original list `cs`.

With the `add-count` procedure defined, a procedure `reduce-counts` could be defined that goes through all of the counts and accumulates them to an empty list by using `add-count`. The resulting list will have the counts combined.

```lisp
(define (reduce-counts cs (acc '()))
  (if (null? cs)
      acc
      (reduce-counts (rest cs) (add-count acc (first cs)))))
```

Here is a test run:

```
reduce-counts.rkt> (define test-counts '(("cry" 1) ("racket" 2) ("cry" 3) ("play" 4) ("racket" 5) ("play" 6) ("racket" 7)))
reduce-counts.rkt> (reduce-counts test-counts)
'(("racket" 14) ("play" 10) ("cry" 4))
```

As an alternative approach you could use `filter` to collect counts with similar tags in a list, and combine those into a new count after summing the values. The combined counts can be collected in an accumulator before filtering the input to remove the tags which were just combined. This process can be repeated recursively until all counts have been combined, removed, and collected.

```lisp
;;; An alternate solution
(define (combine-like-counts cs)
  (list (get-tag (first cs))
        (foldl (lambda (c x) (+ x (get-val c))) 0 cs)))

(define (reduce-counts cs (acc '()))
  (if (null? cs)
      acc
      (let* ((k (get-tag (first cs)))
             (k-tag? (lambda (c) (equal? k (get-tag c))))
             (like (filter k-tag? cs))
             (remaining (filter (negate k-tag?) cs)))
        (reduce-counts remaining
                       (cons (combine-like-counts like) acc)))))
```

Here the `combine-like-counts` procedure assumes that all counts in the input list share the same tag, so a new count is formed by taking the tag and the sum of all values into a list.

The new `reduce-counts` procedure returns whatever has been placed in the accumulator when the input is the empty list, otherwise the tag of the first count is saved and used to create the `k-tag?` predicate, which is then used with `filter` to create a list of matching counts and a list of the remaining counts with all matching counts removed. The list of matching counts is combined into a single count with `combine-like-counts` and added to the accumulator, which is passed along with `remaining` recursively to `reduce-counts`.

This works as before, although the ordering has changed:

```
reduce-counts.rkt> (define test-counts '(("cry" 1) ("racket" 2) ("cry" 3) ("play" 4) ("racket" 5) ("play" 6) ("racket" 7)))
reduce-counts.rkt> (reduce-counts test-counts)
'(("play" 10) ("racket" 14) ("cry" 4))
```

I would suspect that these two implementations would have different performance characteristics depending on the particulars of their input data. My hunch is that the second would fare better for large input that contained large quantities of each tag, but the real answer would come from testing on some representative data samples.

If you are really concerned about performance for large amounts of data, you might consider converting the data to a [hash table](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/hashtables.html#%28tech._hash._table%29) and using some of the built-in [dictionary procedures](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/dicts.html) to arrive at a similar solution.

Comment: Well, I finally had some time to test with a dataset. On a list with 40k words (where the frequencies range from 1 to like 30000 for the most popular words) my solution took 2.5s, your first solution took 22s and your last solution took about 120s.. Using 200k words, my solution took about 51s and yours 568s (I didn't have enough time to test the last one). But thank you, perhaps I should've tried to test before asking (I expected mine to be quite slow since it loops like 4 times through the list), but at least I got a way to compare now.

Comment: I'm a little bit surprised at the differences in timing, but there is quite a bit of consing going on in my solutions; I'll do some testing later when I get some time. I think that using hash tables would improve performance.

Comment: Are you sure about those timings? I just tried quick timings of all three solutions on a set of 10,000 random counts and got about 8 seconds for your posted code, and 9 milliseconds for both of my solutions. For 50,000 counts I got 104s for yours, and 48ms for both of mine. This could change with a larger and differently distributed test set. Of course, I collected garbage before the timings, but your solution spent over half of the time collecting garbage anyway. I may have botched copying your code to test it; I'll look at it again later.

Comment: Well, that's interesting. Maybe it depends on the words or something else, I don't know.. but yes those were the times that I got.

Comment: After playing around some more with this, it looks like all three solutions are sensitive to the way the counts are distributed, i.e., whether or not there are lots of duplicate counts. Each of them wins in some scenarios, and each of them loses badly in others. That's exactly why we have to test this sort of thing against representative inputs to decide what will work best ;)